# Return sums instead of values in pivot table like SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a nice little query that does almost what I need it to except for one little bit. Instead of returning the values under the columns "Orange" and "Lemon" I need to know how many submissions for that attribute and fruit.

Here is my table and some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE `fruits` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fruit` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fruit_attribute` varchar(11) DEFAULT '',
  `submissions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `fruits` (`id`, `fruit`, `fruit_attribute`, `submissions`)
VALUES
    (1,'Orange','tough peel',59),
    (2,'Lemon','tough peel',70),
    (3,'Orange','citrus',100),
    (4,'Orange','juice',90),
    (5,'Lemon','juice',75),
    (6,'Lemon','tart',35),
    (7,'Lemon','citurs',65),
    (8,'Orange','breakfast',110),
    (9,'Lemon','lemonaid',120),
    (10,'Orange','florida',50);
```

And here is the query:

```
SELECT
  fruit_attribute, submissions,
  MAX(IF(t1.fruit = 'Orange', t1.fruit_attribute, NULL)) AS Orange,
  MAX(IF(t1.fruit = 'Lemon', t1.fruit_attribute, NULL)) AS Lemon
FROM fruits t1
GROUP BY
  fruit_attribute;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle page for a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/290bf/5)

All help is most appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain what the result should be? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: I'm looking for the amount of submissions for each attribute for each fruit.

Comment: just post expected result for the sample you already provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to sum the `submissions` column:

```
SELECT fruit_attribute,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fruit = 'Orange' THEN t1.submissions ELSE 0 END) AS Orange,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fruit = 'Lemon' THEN t1.submissions ELSE 0 END) AS Lemon
FROM fruits t1
GROUP BY fruit_attribute;
```

I prefer using `CASE` to `IF()`, because `CASE` is standard an available in almost all databases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the number of submissions, then use sum() with if() inside instead of the max():

```
SUM(IF(t1.fruit = 'Orange', submissions, 0)) AS Orange
```

Comment: This counts the number of rows, it doesn't add up all the `submissions` columns.

Comment: I interpreted the question this way. OP's comment to the question was not available at that time.